# Android Studio issue with HAXM

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, haxm

I am trying android studio 3.1 canary 5 release 
And when i created an avd of nexus 5 api 27 getting issue/warning reported in macintosh 10.13.2

After looking over to issue as mentioned to install HAXM of >=6.2.1

```
7:21 PM Emulator: WARNING: HAXM 6.1.2 is installed. Please install HAXM >= 6.2.1 to fix compatibility issues on Mac.
```

Tried below intel site but couldn't find updated version above 6.2.1

```
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm
```

Help is required on same to find updated version for mac.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I had the same problem. Every time I ran the emulator I got the same message:
Emulator: WARNING: HAXM 6.1.2 is installed. Please install HAXM >= 6.2.1

Emulator was very slow and unresponsive. But Android Studio 3.0 indicated that I'd had the HAXM 6.2.1 installed. HAXM version above 6.2.1 is nonexistent, so I guess it's AS issue. I was able to fix the problem by simply uninstalling the HAXM and installing it again at the path:

**Android Studio (3.0) => Tools => Android => SDK manager => SDK tools => Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)**

Just unchecked that box, hit **Apply** and AS uninstalled the HAXM. Then clicked the same box and AS installed it again. Emulator is now running smooth and error message disappeared.

Comment: Strange, cannot uncheck boxes on that dialog, only Android Repository and Offline Repo.

Answer (score 3):

Same here but I could fix it to re-install "Intel 86x Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) ", simply uncheck the checkbox and click Apply button, then check the box and apply again on SDK Tools window.

Answer (score 2):

For me, re-installing the HAXM didn't work; other problems would consistently crop up.  I just uninstalled HAXM (as per other answers) and just left that part disabled.  At least I have a running emulator.

I guess that the mac HAXM system is still pretty buggy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update HAXM.

Open **Android Studio**

Goto **Tools>Android>SDK Manager>SDK Tools**

there will be "`Intel 86x Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` " in list. just update it or Install it.

Answer is for (Android Studio =>3.0)

Comment: Yes Zaid, already tried with above step to install or update HAXM.

But problem with emulator launch. As soon as i launch emulator it starts with earlier mentioned error in android studio.

Comment: It is already installed. The version on the mac is 6.2.1 already

Comment: Same issue with me.  I already have Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) installed.  Of course, everything worked great _before_ I updated.  Sigh.

Answer (score -1):

1-Close Your Project
2- Close Android Studio
3- open  Control Panel>Uninstall a program > top left is written that "Turn windows features on or off" click on it and
4- find Hyper-V (Check and click ok) finally rebot your pc

This solution is 1000% Working.
if you didn'n understand Contact us via WhatsApp +16193545271

Comment: Don't share personal information via your Responses, it may end up being used in ways you don't want 

Comment: hello, this works for me. but probably disabled haxm because of hyper-v enabling.