# What is this error when run android studio?

Tags: android-studio

When I execute in android studio i get the this error:

[image]

Comment: maybe you should check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31458503/6176003

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

Answer (score 0):

You have to `enable HAXM`. Found a fast link [check it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870120/android-studio-issue-with-haxm) and follow the steps.